# jQuery click event works in Chrome, not in Firefox or IE

Tags: jquery, html, internet-explorer, firefox, click

This small function sets some divs to hidden upon page load, then shows or hides them when an arrow icon is clicked.

This works well in Chrome, but in FF and IE everything is visible with page load and clicking on the icon does nothing.

I am new to jQuery and have read some other questions but cannot see the solution.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".each-panel").hide();
  $(".additional_comments").hide();
  $(".summaryArrowUp").hide();

  $(".summaryArrowRight").click(function(){
    $(".each-panel").slideDown("slow");
    $(".additional_comments").slideDown("slow");
    $(".summaryArrowRight").hide();
    $(".summaryArrowUp").show();
  });

  $(".summaryArrowUp").click(function(){
    $(".each-panel").slideUp("slow");
    $(".additional_comments").slideUp("slow");
    $(".summaryArrowRight").show();
    $(".summaryArrowUp").hide();
  });
```

Here is the HTML:

```
<div id="capSummaryContainer" class="infoBoxLine">
  <h3 class="buildSummary">Build Summary 
    <span><i class="fa fa-chevron-right summaryArrowRight" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-chevron-up summaryArrowUp" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </span>
  </h3>
  <div class="each-panel hidden">
    <div class="insider" id="capSummaryContainer_custom"></div>
  </div>
  <!-- Front panel contents -->
  <div class="each-panel">
    <h4 class="heading">Front Panel 
      <span>
        <i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true" onclick="selectTab(2);"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true" onclick="skiptomylootDelete(2, 'Are you sure you want to remove all customization from the front of the cap?');"></i>
      </span>
    </h4>
    <div class="insider" id="capSummaryContainer_front">
      <div class="designname"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Left panel contents -->
  <div class="each-panel">
    <h4 class="heading">Left Panel
      <span>
        <i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true" onclick="selectTab(3);"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true" onclick="skiptomylootDelete(3, 'Are you sure you want to remove all customization from the left side of the cap?');"></i>
      </span>
    </h4>
    <div class="insider" id="capSummaryContainer_left">
      <div class="designname"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Any error in console? BTW, your JavaScript has syntax errors.

Comment: There is not enought code to reproduce an issue. All posted looks like to be working... But `selectTab()` and `skiptomylootDelete()` are undefined... Because not posted.

Comment: The answers below only added a closing bracket `});` to the ready function and a closing `</div>`... What I also did when I was telling there is no problem to reproduce...

Comment: Thank you - I was actually able to get this to work well in all browsers by hiding my div initially with CSS instead of jQuery and nesting the code inside of another function that had event wiring- I think the document.ready was possibly in more than one place and it was confusing the browsers. This is part of a very large and difficult to navigate project and I hadn't realized there was another document.ready function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try my example. I just added the icons as default because i didn't have the time to attach fontawesome. Tested with FF and IE and Chrome. When properly formatted I found some missing brackets that may or maynot be in your main code. Please test for yourself in FF and IE if this example works.

```js
$(".each-panel").hide();
$(".additional_comments").hide();
$(".summaryArrowUp").hide();

$(".summaryArrowRight").click(function() {
  $(".each-panel").slideDown("slow");
  $(".additional_comments").slideDown("slow");
  $(".summaryArrowRight").hide();
  $(".summaryArrowUp").show();
});

$(".summaryArrowUp").click(function() {
  $(".each-panel").slideUp("slow");
  $(".additional_comments").slideUp("slow");
  $(".summaryArrowRight").show();
  $(".summaryArrowUp").hide();
});
```

```css
i {
  color: blue;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 3px;
  background: #CCC;
}

i:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="capSummaryContainer" class="infoBoxLine">
  <h3 class="buildSummary">Build Summary
    <span>
      <i class="fa fa-chevron-right summaryArrowRight" aria-hidden="true">[>]</i>
      <i class="fa fa-chevron-up summaryArrowUp" aria-hidden="true">[^]</i>
    </span>
  </h3>
  
  <div class="each-panel hidden">
    <div class="insider" id="capSummaryContainer_custom"></div>
  </div>
  
  <!-- Front panel contents -->
  <div class="each-panel">
    <h4 class="heading">
      Front Panel
      <span>
        <i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true" onclick="selectTab(2)"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true" onclick="skiptomylootDelete(2, 'Are you sure you want to remove all customization from the front of the cap?');"></i>
      </span>
    </h4>
    <div class="insider" id="capSummaryContainer_front">
      <div class="designname"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <!-- Left panel contents -->
  <div class="each-panel">
    <h4 class="heading">
      Left Panel
      <span>
        <i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true" onclick="selectTab(3);"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true" onclick="skiptomylootDelete(3, 'Are you sure you want to remove all customization from the left side of the cap?');"></i>
      </span>
    </h4>
    <div class="insider" id="capSummaryContainer_left">
      <div class="designname"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: It would help if you explain what you changed... And please, indent your code better than this.

Comment: Please read above, and my code is indented. Open the code editor and you will see I have used standard tabs indicating an indent.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".each-panel").hide();
  $(".additional_comments").hide();
  $(".summaryArrowUp").hide();

  $(".summaryArrowRight").click(function() {
    $(".each-panel").slideDown("slow");
    $(".additional_comments").slideDown("slow");
    $(".summaryArrowRight").hide();
    $(".summaryArrowUp").show();
  });

  $(".summaryArrowUp").click(function() {
    $(".each-panel").slideUp("slow");
    $(".additional_comments").slideUp("slow");
    $(".summaryArrowRight").show();
    $(".summaryArrowUp").hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="capSummaryContainer" class="infoBoxLine">
  <h3 class="buildSummary">Build Summary <span><i class="fa fa-chevron-right summaryArrowRight" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-chevron-up summaryArrowUp" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></h3>
  <div class="each-panel hidden">
    <div class="insider" id="capSummaryContainer_custom"></div>
  </div>
  <!-- Front panel contents -->
  <div class="each-panel">
    <h4 class="heading">Front Panel
      <span><i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true" onclick="selectTab(2);"></i>
        <i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true" onclick="skiptomylootDelete(2, 'Are you sure you want to remove all
                                                           customization from the front of the cap?');"></i></span></h4>
    <div class="insider" id="capSummaryContainer_front">
      <div class="designname"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Left panel contents -->
  <div class="each-panel">
    <h4 class="heading">Left Panel <span>
      <i class="fa fa-eye" aria-hidden="true" onclick="selectTab(3);"></i>
      <i class="fa fa-trash" aria-hidden="true" onclick="skiptomylootDelete(3, 'Are you sure you want to remove all customization from the left side of the cap?');"></i></span>
    </h4>
    <div class="insider" id="capSummaryContainer_left">
      <div class="designname"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

It seems you didnt complete the tags properly, [this](https://jsfiddle.net/durga598/tcrt6Lzo/) works in all broweser

Answer (score -1):

You can try .on click() event instead of .click(). Here is one example,

```
$(document).on('click', '.summaryArrowRight', function () 
{
// your function here
});
```

Hope it works.